# Display Glitches

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, gpu-driver, powerpc

I am trying to install Lubuntu 12.10 on a PPC G5. I Dban'd the original HDD and booted the DVD, but when I clicked on the "Install Lubuntu" icon a null window comes up. It says "Install" In the very center but other than that, nothing else is visible. I clicked the X to close it out and a "Quit the installation?" box appears also with nothing else visible.

Several other windows do the same thing, like setting up  the network, etc. Luckily firefox opens, but the home page is iffy with pixelated graphics. The main desktop looks a tad pixelated as well.

```
G5 Specs
PPC G5, 2.5 DP PCI-X PPC 970fx
4GB DDR1 PC3200
160.0Gb 7200RPM HDD
ATI Radeon 9600 XT (AGP 8x Pro) Video Card
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is with the video card.

I have a Radeon 9600 in my G5 PPC. I followed the steps on this [Lubuntu wiki help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/FAQ/PPC#No_desktop_with_Radeon_video_chips_on_LiveCD)

During the initial CD boot process, at the boot: prompt type:

```
live video=radeonfb:1024x768-32@60
```

where `1024x768` is your `xy` resolution, `32` is the `bpp` and `60` is the refresh rate in Hertz. In general, these default settings should suffice for most people.

This fixes the pixellation when trying to then install Lubuntu onto your PPC.

After installation, there should be no further problems.

You can identify your video chip with

```
lspci | grep -i vga
```

The linked page has instructions for nVidia card issues and sound problems as well.